# how to kill process in Mac OS X and not have it restart on its own

Tags: macos, terminal, services, kill, launchd

When I run `sudo kill -9 [PID]` with the proper process ID, the process stops but then is restarted and has a new PID. I'm trying to kill the `mysqld` process.

How can I mimic the Activity Monitor in killing a process? In the Activity Monitor, when you press "Quit Process", the process permanently stops running, it is totally terminated. I figure that `kill` will do the same thing right?

I had both the Activity Monitor and the terminal next to each other to see if the command works, but every time I do `sudo kill -9 [PID]`, the process in Activity monitor doesn't go away, it just refreshes with a new PID.

So... how do I kill the `mysqld` process via the terminal?

Comment: I did it from the activity monitor because the 'kill' command was not recognising the PID. Again unlike your case my mysqld did not restart as soon as I killed it from the Activity monitor.

Comment: Ouch! Don't use -9 unless you REALLY need to. It's a violent thing to do to a process. Other signals allow a process to terminate in an orderly manner, but not -9! So it means that RAM buffers don't get flushed to disk, for example. This is a particularly bad thing to do to a database that is in the process of doing work; you'll come back to damaged tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried to kill the process by sending it the `TERM` signal, and that worked. The command was:

```
sudo kill -15 {PID}
```

Answer (score 34):

The process you are killing is probably being managed by [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html), the proper way to stop it and have it not restart is to use `launchctl unload <path to plist>`. The plist that controls that process is in either `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`. If it is a system process and not one of your own, then you will probably have to use `sudo` to get `launchctl` to work as desired.

A better way try and stop it might be;

```
${MYSQL_HOME}/bin/mysqladmin -u root -proot shutdown > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm trying to kill the `mysqld` process. I'm not sure if that is part of LaunchDaemons... but the following command is the correct way to stop the server from running `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop` but I'm having problems with that, so I'm trying to kill the process directly.

Comment: if it is being restated after `kill -9` the launchd is probably involved, even if indirectly. you can tell by using `launchctl list`

Comment: the list doesn't have "mysql" in it. I will try your command up top.

Comment: Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null.

Comment: Using `-15` as a flag opposed to `-9` did the job. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I had the same problem and was able to solve by removing mysql from launchd via 

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Comment: The `launchd` link is now broken.

Comment: I can see `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` in /Library/LaunchDaemons and have used the command `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` only to receive the error message: `Could not find specified service`

Answer (score 23):

A couple of comments mention that "launchd is probably involved" - so I thought I'd put this out as an additional answer. As @jarrod-roberson says, you can check if launchd is involved by first running `launchctl list | grep mysqld`.

An important thing you learn here is whether MySQL was installed with Homebrew or not - Brew stores its `launchctl` files in a different location than where OSX puts the "regular" services.

On my OSX box, the `plist` files are in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` So I ran:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

to stop the MySQL server. I had previously looked in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and `/Library/LaunchAgents` but didn't find a file with `mysqld` in its name.

You can also install a brew-based system called `services`, to manage all Brew-installed services applications, as described in this post - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew I haven't tried this myself, though, so YMMV.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Always a pain when you are fighting multiple different ways to run a LAMP stack locally.

Comment: I had to use the Homebrew path to remove this, i.e. `/usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

Answer (score 14):

For me, this worked once I figured out which label I was looking for.

```
launchctl list | egrep {DESIRED_LABEL}   
launchctl remove {DESIRED_LABEL}
```

Comment: This helps me to finally kill Pulse Secure. Just note that the label for egrep can be partial keywords (like pulse), but the label for remove must be copied from the list output (like net.pulsesecure.pulsetray).

Answer (score 7):

Unload the service and stop the daemon:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Load the service and start the daemon:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Comment: This worked for me except that is was `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`  My local MySQL was installed from downloading from MySQL, not via homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

What process are you trying to kill? Some processes in Mac OS X (e.g., the Dock, some system processes) automatically respawn if they're killed.

Comment: I'm trying to kill the `mysqld` process

Comment: Probably managed by `launchd`, then, which will restart it if the process dies.

Answer (score 2):

I solved editing the /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist file, changing the attribute true to false

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false />
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a process running on your machine that is blocking mysql. Run

`ps auxwww | grep mysql`

then do

`kill -15 {PID}`

My process that was blocking it was _mysql