# How to kill a zombie process on a mac

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app

How to kill a zombie process or find it's parent process on a Mac using the Terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to kill process in Mac OS X and not have it restart on its own](http://superuser.com/questions/159486/how-to-kill-process-in-mac-os-x-and-not-have-it-restart-on-its-own)

Comment: @soandos Not a duplicate, as that topic isn't about zombies. None of the `kill` signals work for zombies IIRC. I've had this happen before.

Comment: Usually one can kill zombies if the parent process is known but this requires killing that one too, which is not always a pleasant choice. Therefore I am wondering if there is another solution to this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hack Saw says:

> **Sadly**, it appears that killing of zombies is all about **killing the parent**, and if the parent is /sbin/launchd, you can kill it only with rebooting.

It would be a Very Bad Idea to kill `launchd`, but you can tell it to HUP.

Try `sudo kill -s HUP 1`

That will cause `launchd` to reinitialize without restarting. This has worked for me in the past (wrt. removing zombie entries).

Answer (score 3):

**Sadly**, it appears that killing of zombies is all about **killing the parent**, and if the parent is /sbin/launchd, you can kill it only with rebooting.

I'm getting zombies from using Xcode, and stopping the simulator, and it's handing the zombies to my own personal /sbin/launchd, which *didn't go away* when I logged out.

**ps -xo pid,ppid,stat,command** will show you your processes, with their parent ID in the second column.

Answer (score 2):

zombie processes are already dead and cannot be killed. They should be removed from the process table automatically when the parent process dies.

They do not slow down your machine and you can leave them there (they are just entries in the process table).

There is a maximum number of processes (you can check it with `sysctl kern.maxproc`) and zombie processes will reduce it (as they are counted).

If you reach this limit you will not be able to create new processes and you will be forced to reboot.

Comment: "Should be removed", but they're not always. Xcode is terrible about leaving zombie processes, and they aren't cleaned up even if Xcode dies / is quit / is killed.

Comment: @JRG-Developer I agree but they are not a problem. They do no consume any resource.

Comment: Actually they are a problem when too many are created and fork can't launch any new process and you're forced to reboot.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you are correct. They do not slow down your computer but they reserve resources. On my Mac (8GB of RAM) the limit is set to 2048. I updated my answer

Comment: They are a problem when you want to restart the crashed process, and use it again, but can't without rebooting.

Comment: Why should they be a problem?

Comment: When an App gets in that state then you can't relaunch it until the old entry is cleared out. It isn't using any resources but the pollution of the table prevents a new instance from launching, therefore you're blocked until you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the parent process using `lldb -p <parent pid>` and then call `expr (int)::waitpid(<child pid>, NULL, 0)`

This will reap the exit status of the child zombie in the parent, and thus remove the zombie process from the process table.

Comment: This sounds like a great answer, but omits how to find `<parent pid>` in the first place. Can you add how to do that?

Comment: ps -o ppid -p <pid of zombie>