# OSX Dock - programs that are supposedly "running" are not able to be started

Tags: macos, dock

I have a following situation.  OSX puts a dot in a Dock under a program icon which is running. If a program malfunctions (say eats whole RAM) it can be killed by "Force Quit" command issued from the Dock,  or from Activity Monitor/Terminal by "kill PID".
I have managed to achieve a situation where Dock says "application not responding/Force Quit", but at the same time I am sure the program is not running as I have just killed it from the Terminal (typically it changes also the status of the program in dock, but not this time).

It seems that some subprocess is holding the Dock

"killall Dock" does not help (after it restarts my program has exactly the same status).

How one can clean this mess up without restarting the machine? Is it possible to get the PID of the process which is associated to a particular Dock icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a zombie process on a mac](http://superuser.com/questions/390552/how-to-kill-a-zombie-process-on-a-mac)

Comment: AFAIK zombie processes are visible in "ps aux". This one was not.